# Best nutrition-rich supplement for daily living

Tags: nutrition, diet, food

I don't have a very good diet due to my work schedule, but I would like to eat something everyday that is as good for me as possible to hopefully offset some of the negatives of my normal diet.

What food or combination of foods would be best to consume daily in order to reap the most benefit?

I was considering a juicer and something like blueberries, carrots, apples, spinach, etc.

**I don't care about the flavor, necessarily, only about the nutrition/vitamin density.**

I would like the overall cost of ingredients, per serving, to be $3 or less.

Comment: This is debatable as "reaping the most benefit" is somehwat subjective to what you are trying to reap. Weight loss? Muscle gain? Heart health? Bone density? Brain health?

Comment: Weight loss is not an issue, muscle gain is not an issue. I'd like something that promotes heart, brain, and digestive health, if possible, while also helping me guard against as many types of cancers as is feasible.

Comment: There is no supplement that can offset putting junk into your body.

Comment: Off topic per new [FAQ] and a shopping recommendation, too which are generally considered off topic on all .SE sites.

Comment: Thanks, I guess. A recommendation of where it would be better to post it is probably more constructive than just saying "This is off topic."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty broad still, but my best suggestion is to chose what you want from these:

Skim milk shake/smoothie of: protein powder, blueberries, blackberries, raspberries, strawberries, banana, apple(s). Optional acai and pomegranate (or POM wonderful). That gives you your fruit and protein for almost the whole day (depending on size) and won't taste awful. Almost all are anti-oxidant if you're into that thing.

Shake/blend of: spinach, carrots, brocoli, cauliflower, tomatoes, asparagus, bell peppers. Those are the "best" for health.

For healthy food in general, look up something like "What to eat after a heart attack".

Other things include, fish oils, certain nuts and legumes, skim milk.